# Quartz Composer in MacOS X 10.7.3

Tags: macos, xcode

How do I install Quartz Composer in Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Xcode 4.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW1), Apple restructured Xcode — what gets installed (and where) has changed.

From Apple's documentation:

> Several additional tools are no longer part of the default Xcode installation, they are now downloadable as separate packages. The More Developer Tools menu command (Figure 5) provides a direct jump to [developer.apple.com/downloads](http://developer.apple.com/downloads) in Safari where these development tools can be found.
>
> [image: More Dev Tools]

Once you open that and log in with your Apple ID, then download and install "Graphics Tools for Xcode - ...", which includes Quartz Composer.